# The set defined by the orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, projection-matrices

I was solving a GRE-like test and came across the following question (it's argued that the only answer is correct)

> Suppose $A$ is a projector with the symmetric $n \times n \ (n > 2)$ matrix. If $A$ is neither $I$ nor zero, then
>
> (i) Is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^TAx = 1\}$ bounded?
>
> (ii) Is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^TAx = 0\}$ a linear subspace?

As I know a projector with symmetric matrix is defined by a positive semidefinite matrix hence $$x^TAx = 0 \iff Ax = 0$$ but $Ax = 0$ defines a linear subspace therefore (ii) is true. But why (i) isn't true?

If $A$ is symmetric then it's diagonalizable hence there exists an orthogonal $Q$ such that $A = Q^TDQ$ ($D$ is diagonal) so

$$\{x^TAx = 1\} = \{x^TQ^TDxQ = 1\} = \{(Qx)^TDQx = 1\}.$$ But since $A$ is a projector then its eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$ hence $\{(Qx)^TDQx = 1\}$ is something like $\xi_1^2 + \dots+ \xi_k^2 = 1$ but this equation defines a bounded set, as I understand.

Could you please help me to figure out what option is true? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Funny how this question has been alive for $2$ days and no votes, comments, or answers have been given. The community should have bumped this question to the homepage and not have it necessary for you to give it an open bounty. Unfortunately, I am not experienced enough to understand any of this.

Comment: @user477343 yes, I was also surprised. But as I see, bounty doesn't help this question to be answered...maybe it's cursed..

Comment: Perhaps you should bring this up on the **math.metastackexchange** and request for another feature more likely to get other users to answer abandoned questions like this one.

Comment: @user477343 thank you for your advice. I will try it

Comment: No problem, unless there exist questions out there of similar sort, which would mean that your post will just be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for statement (i) is almost correct except for the last step. Given the equation$$
ξ_1^2 + \cdots + ξ_k^2 = 1,
$$
if $k < n$, then this equation defines an **unbounded** set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since $ξ_{k + 1}, \cdots, ξ_n$ can be any real numbers.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks a lot